# why Application contexts in oracle uses PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g, applicationcontext

why do we use package to retrieve session data and set a database session context.
what i am trying to say is that when we create a Logon Trigger for the package
why don't we write code in trigger for retrieve and setting up session.
why should we need to use procedure and package
ex.

1. Create Trigger set_empno_ctx_trig After LogON ON DATABASE Begin
2. sysadmin_ctx.set_empno_ctx_pkg.set_empno; //Here we call procedure
   i wonder why i need to call procedure,can't we write same code here inside trigger.
3. END;

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simple answer is that we could write the code directly in the trigger.  It's just considered bad practice to do so.

Why?  Partly because code in stored procedures is potentially re-usable, and code in triggers isn't.  But also because code in triggers tends to be overlooked, which makes debugging harder.  This is obviously a circular argument, because the main reason why people tend to overlook code in triggers is because it is considered bad practice to put code there.  However that's teh way it is.

There is also a school of thought that [triggers are inherently evil](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?#q=oracle+triggers+are+evil), although that applies more to DML triggers, rather than the kind of system trigger you have here.

---

The other pertinent thing is that application contexts must be associated with a PL/SQL package.  That's the way Oracle has implemented them.  So there is no choice in this regard.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5003.htm#SQLRF01202).

Comment: Your link is invalid.